# @Autowired is not working with external application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have 2 applications for example app1 and app2. I am using app2's jar in app1. app2 has an service interface whose implementation is in app1. I want to inject app1's serviceImpl into app2. But it is not working with annotation. But its working with xml file entry. I also added component-scan for app2 in xml. Please help me out.

App2:

```
public interface InterTransactionService {

    public List<MappingDetail> getMappingDetailsById(Integer mappingMasterId) throws InterTransactionException;
    public List<DimensionMappingDetail> getDimensionMappingDetailsById(Integer mappingDetailId) throws InterTransactionException;
}
```

App1:

```
@Service("interTransactionService")
public class InterTransactionServiceImpl implements InterTransactionService{
//implementation of methods
}
```

App2:

```
@Service
@Scope(value=BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE,proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class ETLImpl extends AbstractInstanceGeneratorService{

    @Qualifier("interTransactionService")
    @Autowired
    private InterTransactionService interTransactionService;
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private xx.generator.InterTransactionService xx.generator.ETLImpl.interTransactionService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [xx.generator.InterTransactionService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=interTransactionService), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: This question is impossible to answer in its current form. Please could you add a the relevant code demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Is the `component-scan` picking up the package that `ETLImpl` is in? Also could you please add the `XML` that _does_ work and also add the error you are seeing, or is it just that App2 interTransactionService is null?

Comment: yes component-scan is picking up the base the package of ETLImpl.